# Uv Maps Faces Objects Materials And Image Texutres.png

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In a nut shell I just don't get it when I start unwraping multiple faces on one object. I don't see how the *UV/Image Editor* the UV Maps, the Nodes and the materials are logically connected.

If the UV images editor said "You are editing the material named such and such" then I would see what was going on. I don't understand what I am affecting when I click on the UV Maps under data object.

Are the UVMaps connected to the unwrap via osmosis?
(repeated in comment)

Comment: In a nut shell I just dont get it when I start unwraping multiple faces on one object.  I dont see how the UV images editor the UVMAPS  and the nodes and the materials are logically connected.  If the UV images editor said " YOu are editing the material named such and such then I would see what was going on.   I dont undestand what I am affecting when I click on the UV Maps under data object.  Are the UVMAPS connected to the unwrap via osmosis ?

Comment: Please keep question short and straight to the point. What you wrote in the comment was enough

Answer (score 1):

You don't edit *materials* in the UV Editor, you only edit coordinates for applying textures.

These sets of coordinates called a *UV Map* are created through the process of *Unwrapping* can be used in any number of textures for any materials, modifiers, for texture painting, or any other use you desire.

They are not tied to any particular material or texture for that matter, and each object can have any number of different sets of coordinates for different purposes.

Each object can have any number of materials applied to it's faces called *Material Slots*. Each slot can hold exactly one material, and each face can be assinged to exactly one Slot at any given moment.

Each material can make use of any number of textures, and each different texture must use at least on set of coordinates. These coordinates can be automatic like *Generated* or *Object*, or manually created through UV Unwrapping like UVMaps

Now [go watch some tutorials about Blender unwrapping](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender%20beginner%20unwrapping)

Comment: " each different texture must use at least on set of coordinates."  how do I reveal the set of cordinates for a texture ?

Comment: Depends, which render engine do you use? For Cycles there is a *Texture Coordinates* node which can output several types of coordinates and a UV Node for specific UV Maps. You can specify and name different UV Maps for each mesh under the *Properties Window > Object Data > UV Maps*