# Why I can't see my textures on Game Engine?

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine

I've put many textures to my objects with UV editing, but on the Game Engine I can't see them.

I watched video about how to do it and I added a material for every object, I also added the same textures with the materials, but nothing happens.

This is my project on Game Engine.How to make the textures to be seen?
[image: Screenshot]

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about your project, like what materials you are using, with what settings, how you unwrapped your objects and what viewport settings you are using.

Comment: I used texture as viewpoint shading,I downloaded the textures from textures.com,then in UV editing I marked every object and selected unwrap on Edit Mode.

Comment: Unwrapping is not the same as applying a texture. Unwrapping generated UV coordinates which can then be used in a material where said texture is used. See [my answer about UV and textures](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69652/uv-maps-faces-objects-materials-and-image-texutres-png/69653#69653) for more details

Comment: It is UV map on my project for UV coordinates at every object,not generated.Is this the problem or not?